# Trouble with cygwin and hadoop 2.6.1 - null\bin\winutils.exe

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, hbase

I want to run hadoop 2.6.1 on cygwin64. (Later I want to run hBsae,too)
The problem is, that I start `start-dfs.sh`, I will get this exception:

```
 15/10/07 21:13:54 ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary    in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.preProcessForWindows(GenericOptionsParser.java:438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf.main(GetConf.java:331)
```

Okay, I know that this is a well known problem and some solutions in this forum say something about adding `HADOOP_HOME` to the envirements. But the problem is still available.
this is a snippet of my `bash_profile`:

```
# cygwin path translation

export JAVA_HOME=$(cygpath -u $(cygpath -m -s "${JAVA_HOME}"))
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/home/user/hadoop-2.6.1

export PATH=$PATH:$(cygpath -u $(cygpath -m -s "${JAVA_HOME}\bin")):/home/user/hadoop-2.6.1/bin
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/user/hadoop-2.6.1

export HADOOP_HOME=/home/user/hadoop-2.6.1/
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=/home/user/hadoop-2.6.1/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
```

an `echo $HADOOP_HOME` also prints the path. But why is the path of winutils incomplete? Or is there a variable that I ferget?

greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up winutils.exe in your PATH (environment variable).

Comment: Winutils is in the bin directory of HADOOP_INSTALL. THIS path is included and exported.

Comment: Can you try  and give the complete path  (including the file name winUtils.exe) ?  This worked for me  for the same error. Though I set up windows absolute path in PATH environment variable. like C:\mydir\winutils.exe

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem. Set up windows environment variable was the trick... I set variables at the bash profile. Thank you

Comment: Good to know that it solved. Can you please accept the answer.